# Empty object is invisible

Tags: empty

Im using an empty cube to act as a target for an animation, but for some reason when I opened my project, all my empties had gone [image: invisible] and i don't know how to fix it. Any tips?

Comment: Has the Empty visibility entry somehow got disabled on the Object Types Visibility dropdown? (Leftmost eye icon on the R/H side of the top toolbar next to the Viewport Overlays dropdown.)

Comment: please upload your blend file if John's answer doesn't help so we can check it out

Comment: Hello, sorry for awnsering so late but ends up the extra overlays were disabled, thats why it wouldn't show up

Answer (score 1):

*View Object Types* next to the *Show Overlay* button, check if any of them are hidden.